# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'should') in commands.js

Tags: cypress

I don't know why cypress is not reading assertions in commands.js file. Why?

TypeError
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'should')

```
import LoginPage from '../PageObjects/LoginPage';

const loginPage = new LoginPage();

Cypress.Commands.add('ManualLogin', () => {
    const email = 'testemail'
    const password = 'testpassword'
  loginPage.getEmailInput().should('be.visible').type(email);
  loginPage.getPasswordInput().should('be.visible').type(password);
  loginPage.getLoginButton().should('be.visible').click();
});
```

Comment: To understand why, you will have to provide details of `LoginPage`.

Comment: The selector was invalid.